# Single-handedly mark as duplicate by 2 users

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, close-reasons, dupehammer

I just came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36152770/specify-default-path-in-gnu-shell-startup). This question has been tagged with both [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash) & [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git).

It was marked as duplicate by two gold badge owners (@tripleee & @vonc) of either of the 2 tags (bash & git respectively).

As we know, gold badge owners of the tag can single-handedly mark a question as 'duplicate'.
When one person has already marked it as duplicate & closed it, the other person will already see it as closed/on-hold. Thus, cannot re-vote for close.

So, who was the one to mark it as duplicate (I guess that was VonC, as per the 'marked as duplicate by' line).
& How was it decided about who have marked it as duplicate?

Comment: The most probable explanation is that tripleee did not vote to close the question as a duplicate, but chose another close reason.

Comment: I did cast the final close vote as duplicate. Is there any problem?

Comment: The other vote was an "off-topic" one.

Comment: OK... because it said, "marked as duplicate by triplee & vonc"... That confused me. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54917/distinguish-close-votes-by-reason